# windows 8 store javascript app, download and save images from web

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a requirement where i have to download the images from the web url and save them to some folders in picture library. note that it is an jabvascript app (winJS). I tried some of the examples and had no luck.

below are some of the codes i tried:

method 1:

```
var download = null;
var promise = null;
function DownloadFile(uriString, fileName) {
    try {
        // Asynchronously create the file in the pictures folder.
        Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName).done(function (newFile) {
            var uri = Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriString);
            var downloader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader();

            // Create a new download operation.
            download = downloader.createDownload(uri, newFile).startAsync().then(complete, error, progress);

            // Start the download and persist the promise to be able to cancel the download.
            promise = download.startAsync().then(complete, error, progress);
        }, error);
    } catch (err) {
        // displayException(err);
    }
};
```

method 2:

```
    function downloadFile(uri) {
 var localFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;
     var thumbnail = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.createFromUri(Windows.Foundation.Uri(uri));
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile.createStreamedFileFromUriAsync("photo.jpg", Windows.Foundation.Uri(uri), thumbnail).done(function (newFile) {
            /* Your success and error handlers */

            localFolder.createFileAsync("photo2.jpg", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
              .then(function (file) {
                  newFile.copyAndReplaceAsync(file);

              });

           });
    }
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do (and don't forget to declare in your manifest the capability to access to the picture library):

```
function downloadFileAsync(targetUrl , fileName) {
      return  WinJS.xhr({
            responseType: "blob",
            type: "GET",
            url: targetUrl,
        }).then(function (response) {
            var fileContents = response.response;
            return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (newFile) {
                return newFile.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite).then(function (stream) {
                    return Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(fileContents.msDetachStream(), stream).then(function () {
                        return stream.flushAsync().then(function () {
                            stream.close();
                            fileContents.msClose();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }); 
}
```